# Open URL from Terminal without "http://" prefix

Tags: terminal

This might be a stupid question, but I will ask it anyway.  When I try to open a URL (like `google.com`) from Terminal using the `open` command, I get the following error:

```
The file /Users/jack/Desktop/google.com does not exist.
 Perhaps you meant 'http://google.com'?"
```

How can I open "http://google.com" without having to use the `http://` prefix?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a difficult time interpreting your question, so this might not even answer your question.

**TL;DR;**

As far as I am aware, there is no way to do what you are asking.  It is possible that there might be a third-party application out there somewhere that will do roughly what you want, but I am not aware of one off the top of my head.

**The longer answer**

The problem here is how your OS processes your request.  When you say "open {name-of-something}, your computer opens the "something" with its default application.  For example, on MacOS, a `.txt` file might get opened with TextEdit.

However, you can also define the **protocol** with which you want to open your "something".  In the case of URLs, you are opening the URL using the `http` protocol.  Your computer knows that anything with the `http://` protocol prefix gets opened in your default web browser (and then your web browser handles it from there).  When you do not add the `http://` prefix, your computer doesn't know that you want to open "google.com" with the `http` protocol, so it thinks it's just a file.

---

Bottom line, you must have the `http://`.

---

*Disclaimer to computer geeks:*  I apologize if this is not the *best* explanation.  I'm self-taught, so some of my vocabulary might be a bit off.